# I've generated resources using Azure Bicep in ADO pipelines. Need to make a new pipeline that will populate the resources with code. Not sure how

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I've got a bicep file that has made the following resources: Function app, storage account, app insights, key vault and app service plan, via a build pipeline in Azure Dev Ops Pipelines. I need to populate these resources with artifacts built from source code e.g. adding functions to the function app. I'm not sure how to do this though. Does anyone have any advice or links to tutorials? I'm new to Azure and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, Azure pipelines working with tasks to deploy artifacts to the resources. These resources can be AKS, IIS or Azure functions as you mentioned. If you particularly looking for Azure function deployment task you can use the [AzureFunction@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/azure-function?view=azure-devops) task for that.

Here is some additional  useful links;

[https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/#:~:text=Azure%20Functions%20is%20an%20event,well%20as%20on%2Dpremises%20systems](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/#:%7E:text=Azure%20Functions%20is%20an%20event,well%20as%20on%2Dpremises%20systems).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml%2Ccsharp